# Need source code of microsoft-intune SDK

Tags: azure-mobile-services, intune

I cannot download the Microsoft ADAL SDK's source code from the github.
I want to override the Intune SDK's features.
Can i get the source code of Microsoft Intune SDK?

Comment: Dear downvoters, may i know the reason for downvote ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code for the Intune App SDK is not publicly available.  If there is a specific feature or capability you'd like to have us consider adding to the SDK, your best route is to add a uservoice feature request here: https://microsoftintune.uservoice.com/forums/291681-ideas

Dave
Microsoft Intune Team

Answer (score 0):

> Can i get the source code of Microsoft Intune SDK?

According to your description, here are the related projects you could refer to them:

- [Intune App SDK for iOS](https://github.com/msintuneappsdk/ms-intune-app-sdk-ios)
- [Intune App SDK for Android](https://github.com/msintuneappsdk/ms-intune-app-sdk-android)

For Xamarin or Cordova app:

- [Intune App SDK Xamarin Component](https://github.com/msintuneappsdk/intune-app-sdk-xamarin)
- [Intune App SDK Cordova Plugin](https://github.com/msintuneappsdk/cordova-plugin-ms-intune-mam)

Comment: Hi Bruce, In those links, MS shared SDKs, frameworks, libs & its dependencies. I am looking for the source code of IntuneSDK/intunelib

Comment: We do not make the SDK source code publicly available.